# when I redirect to an external url, the request gets canceled in browser with normal mode but works in disable security mode

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I'm using this code:

```
$client = new SoapClient('https://ir.zarinpal.com/pg/services/WebGate/wsdl', array('encoding' => 'UTF-8'));

$result = $client->PaymentRequest(
    array(
        'MerchantID' => $transaction->scopeGetMerchantId(),
        'Amount' => $Amount,
        'Description' => $Description,
        'Email' => $Email,
        'Mobile' => $Mobile,
        'CallbackURL' => $CallbackURL
    )
);


//Redirect to URL You can do it also by creating a form
if ($result->Status == 100) {
       return redirect()->away('https://www.zarinpal.com/pg/StartPay/' . $result->Authority);
} else {
    echo 'ERR: ' . $result->Status;
}
```

I also tried `redirect()->to('url')` and `redirect('url')`.

and I'm 100% sure that the condition is true and I'm getting into "if" blocks

[here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PE7Eu.png)

Comment: Why don't redirect with header information via vanilla php? I'm not familiar with laravel sorry,

Comment: @Aaron I've already tried header('Location: url') but it doesn't work either

Comment: Do you send any headers before the code? Then it og course won't work. Enable all errors and check the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you may try to redirect from `non https` to `https` url. If your domain hosted with `https` then it should not caused the issue.

**Solution:**

Suppose application hosted on domain: https://abc.xx
Payment gateway domain: https://xyz.xx

Create a temp url/page in laravel that contains the `javascript`code to redirect on other domain.

**Like:**

1. Suppose user is on page: https://abc.xx/pay, clicked on any button and controller redirect to other laravel temporary page.
2. The temp page: https://abc.xx/processing contains the javascript code.

```
<script language=javascript>
    function redirect(){
      window.location = "http://xyz.xx";
    }
</script>

<body onload="redirect()">

</body>
```

3. Once the view will load it's automatically redirected to the other domain without any restrictions.

Comment: mine is https too

Comment: Then it should not be the issue... possible to share the screenshot?

Comment: if you just add the link as <a href="<link to payment gateway site>"> click me </a> does this work?

Comment: yeah in that case works but I want it to redirect automatically.

Comment: @AlirezaMortezaei just upated the solution... hopefully it works for you.

Comment: I added an image so you can see. when you run browser without security, it works. although it doesn't redirect either but at least returns 200 and html of that page.